# Unable to click device's location permission dialog Allow/Deny button in Android using Appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I am writing automation test for my application but after installing the app. Device's location permission dialog appears this from Android Native permission dialog (com.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity)

When I try to click on the Allow/Deny button it is not working and getting the following error.

```
Running '/Users/a/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","83f0374b42535532","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
[ADB] Found package: 'com.android.packageinstaller' and fully qualified activity name : 'com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity'
[ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.
[ADB] Getting focused package and activity
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running '/Users/a/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","83f0374b42535532","shell","dumpsys","window","windows"]
[ADB] Found package: 'com.android.packageinstaller' and fully qualified activity name : 'com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity'
[ADB] Incorrect package and activity. Retrying.
[ADB] Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: 'com.v.mastertestapplication.MainActivity' never started
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/apk-utils.js:101:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: 'com.v.mastertestapplication.MainActivity' never started
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at ADB.callee$0$0$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/apk-utils.js:101:9)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
```

I have tried the following workarounds but nothing works.

WorkAround 1:

```
protected By getPushNotificationButtonName() {
        return By.id("com.android.packageinstaller:id/permission_allow_button");
    }

public WebElement getQaButton() {
        return AppiumHelper.waitElementToBeVisibleByLocator(getDriver(), getQaButtonElementName());
    }

  public void clickQaButton() throws Exception {
        WebElement qaButton = getQaButton();

        if (qaButton != null) {
            qaButton.click();
        } else {
            elementNotFoundHandler(getQaButtonElementName());
        }
    }
```

WorkAround 2:

```
protected void allowAppPermission(AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver) {
        while (driver.findElements(MobileBy.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][1]")).size() > 0)

        {
            driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.Button'][1]")).click();
        }
    }
```

Find Appium log [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/alkaffkhan28/530af6921366ec400fc7b45ce181765a/raw/350cd4b42c61e7e99679be42e8460e57c40b51f0/Appium_log)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use 'autoGrantPermissions' capability?

```
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
```

This will Accept every permission dialog shown.

Comment: Read this because you are wrong: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Comment: This capability is specific to iOS not for Android. It will work in iOS not in Android

Comment: Have you tried? I am using it in Android... And is at Android Only section... Again, read the website I pasted before... You might be wrong

Comment: This is working. Thanks. 
Sorry I wrongly understand the capability is only for iOS but it is working fine in Android.